How to determine the type of a command line argument in Clap?
I am using Clap (derive) v4.x for a Rust CLI application. The basics, such as command line arguments, environment variable values, and default values, are working properly.  However, I need to determine the Rust type for a command line argument while iterating through the ArgMatches to transform it to a String properly.  If the arg is a String, the parsing in the sample code works.  If the arg is a PathBuf, it fails because the code wants a String.  I'd appreciate your hints for resolving this issue.  Please note that the following code is just for sorting out the solution.  It is not production-level code. :P
/// This is the entry point for the application.
fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    // A simulated value from a .toml configuration file.
    let configfile_value: String = "confignamevalue".to_owned();

    let matches = App::command().get_matches();

    if let Some((_subcommand_name, subcommand_matches)) = matches.subcommand() {

        // Process the Container subcommand.
        let _ = if let "container" = _subcommand_name {
            println!("Subcommand is '{_subcommand_name}'");

            // Not using this file now...  Using a simulated value for initial work.
            let config_file: File = File::open("config.toml").unwrap();

            // Scan the matches looking for any that are from the 'default' source.
            for id in subcommand_matches.ids() {
                println!("Processing id: '{id}'");
                if subcommand_matches.value_source(id.as_str()).unwrap()
                    == ValueSource::DefaultValue
                {
                    println!("Processing id: '{id}' is a DefaultValue");

                    // Determine whether there is a config file value that can override the default one.
                    // >>> ISSUE: THE FOLLOWING ONLY SUPPORTS STRING ARGUMENTS.
                    // >>> HOW CAN I DETERMINE THE TYPE SO I CAN MATCH IT?
                    // >>> match(arg.type()) {
                    // >>>   String => parse the String value
                    // >>>   PathBuf => parse the PathBuf value
                    let arg_value: &String = subcommand_matches.get_one(id.as_ref()).unwrap();
                    println!("Processing id with arg value: '{id}' = '{arg_value}'");

                    if exists_in_config_file(arg_value, &config_file) && *arg_value != configfile_value {
                        // The value in the config file overrides a default value.
                        println!("Setting '{id}' to '{}'", &configfile_value)
                    } else {
                        println!("Retaining '{id}' with value '{}'", arg_value)
                    }
                } else {
                    println!(
                        "Processing id: '{id}' is a {:?} ",
                        subcommand_matches.value_source(id.as_str()).unwrap()
                    )
                }
            }
        };
    } else {
        // Other subcommands
        unreachable!()
    };
    Ok(())
}

fn exists_in_config_file(arg_value: &String, config_file: &File) -> bool {
    true
}


An ArgMatches implementation doesn't have this information, it's something you provide. I.e. get_one::<TheTypeYouWant>(…) or like you with a type hint (the String in let value: &String = …) on the assigned to variable.

I see...  So, I can write a generic method and set the type when calling it based on my knowledge of the data to be processed.  Thank you for your assistance!
